# Options for using an unsigned 3rd party applet in Java 1.7.0_51 and later

Tags: java, security, applet

I mostly develop in .NET, but a few of my projects use 3rd-party Java applets, so I'm hoping some Java experts can give me some advice.

The latest version of Java (1.7 update 45) brings up a scary-looking prompt when an unsigned applet launches, warning it could do bad things to the user's PC. This Java version has a built-in expiry date - from January, users will need to update to u51, which will refuse to run unsigned applets at all. These requirements can be sidestepped by users moving the Java Security settings below "minimum recommended", but that's probably not an option for us.

First question: is this summary correct, or have I misunderstood something and we'll be able to carry on with the unsigned applet no problem?

Second, what are my options for dealing with a 3rd-party applet for which the publisher doesn't offer a signed version? I believe I can just sign the jar myself, but are there any technical or legal problems with that idea? The application's only for internal use at my company's sites. We could either sign it with a self-issued certificate, which corporate IT would need to add to the approved list on people's desktops, or we could ask about buying a certificate. Again, any advice on these plans appreciated.

Comment: What I've seen lately is that a .jnlp file gets downloaded and run locally. This avoids the scary looking security warning. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Web_Start#Java_Network_Launching_Protocol_.28JNLP.29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you understand this correctly - [see this blog post from Oracle](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/new_security_requirements_for_rias) detailing what changes will be made in update 51.

Oracle haven't left enterprises completely in the dark though - something they allure to in the last paragraph of that blog post:

> If you are a desktop administrator managing Java installations across a series of computers, consider using [Deployment Rule Sets to whitelist your internal applications](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/introducing_deployment_rule_sets). Deployment Rule Sets allow you to certify that an application is known to be trusted and safe, even if you cannot update the application to adhere to these requirements.

From the documentation:

> The Deployment Rule Set feature enables an enterprise to establish a
>   whitelist of known applications. Applications on the whitelist can be
>   run without most security prompts, however, the following prompts are
>   not suppressed:
>
> - HTTPS security warnings
> - Authentication dialogs that require the user to provide credentials to connect
> - Security warnings from unsigned Java Web Start applications that want to perform such actions as creating a shortcut or an association

The downside is that you'll need to ask your Enterprise Support team to implement this across the company (if it isn't already) and add your applet to the whitelist.

Comment: Great, this sounds like it's designed for exactly the kind of situation I'm in. Thanks!